# SOSL not retrieving correct set of records

Tags: sosl

I need your inputs on the below issue:

Query -

```
FIND {1000} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING
Product2(Id,ProductCode,Universal_Picture_Code__c,Name,Country_Code__c,SAP_Sales_Org__c
WHERE SAP_Sales_Org__c IN ('6014','6005') OR Country_Code__c IN
('DE','CH','AT'))
```

The above query returns 9 records whereas when search text (say '100063') is more specific it returns more number of recrods. This works fine in sandbox but this issue is reproductable in production.Ideally 1000 is subset of 100063 so, 1000 should return more number of records then 100063.

Query with more specific search text -

```
FIND {100063} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING
Product2(Id,ProductCode,Universal_Picture_Code__c,Name,Country_Code__c,SAP_Sales_Org__c
WHERE SAP_Sales_Org__c IN ('6014','6005') OR Country_Code__c IN
('DE','CH','AT'))
```

I am getting the same amount of records when I put the wildcards for both the queries.

Answer (score 0):

1000 is not a superset of 100063; 1000* is a superset that includes 100063. Without wild cards, most pieces of text will return only exact matches. There is some concession for common aliases, such as Bob returning records that contain Robert, or "rose" returning "roses" (singular/plural) but most searches require a wild card if you want to match all records that have a variant, especially numbers. If you searched for 2125557, for example, would you rather return just records that have a phone number matching those seven digits, or phone numbers starting with the area code, followed by 555-7*? Clearly, the latter would be far less useful, so the system tries to make sure that you get exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Here I have tried in the following way: FIND {1000*} In ALL Fields Returning Product2(Fields) Same where filters. Even it is returning the less amount of records when compared to 100063.      Please advise.